# generate unique button id using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

```
<html>
<body>
<div class="table1" id="table" >
</div>

</body>
<script>
var obj, dbparam, x,myObj, txt="";
obj=[
{"Segment":"Segment1","time":"0:00:03:13"},
{"Segment":"Segment2","time":"0:00:03:13"},
{"Segment":"Segment3","time":"0:00:04:13"},
{"Segment":"Segment5","time":"0:00:05:13"},
{"Segment":"Segment4","time":"0:00:06:13"},
{"Segment":"Segment7","time":"0:00:10:13"},
{"Segment":"Segment8","time":"0:00:14:13"},
{"Segment":"Segment9","time":"0:00:13:13"},
{"Segment":"Segment10","time":"0:00:33:13"},
{"Segment":"Segment11","time":"0:00:21:13"},
{"Segment":"Segment12","time":"0:00:18:13"},
{"Segment":"Segment13","time":"0:00:07:13"},
{"Segment":"Segment14","time":"0:00:19:13"}
];
 dbParam = JSON.stringify(obj);
 myObj = JSON.parse(dbParam);

function segments(){
    txt += "<table border='1'>"
    for (x in myObj) {
      txt += "<tr><td>" + myObj[x].Segment + "</td><td>" + myObj[x].time +"</td><td><button  id='x' onclick='popup(myObj[x])'>Edit</button></td><td><button >Save</button></td></tr>";
    }
    txt += "</table>"    
    document.getElementById("table").innerHTML = txt;

}

function popup(x){
alert(x); // always returing last node
}
</script>
</html>
```

I have a dummy JSON data that I want to send it to a table and iterate the JSON data and append it to the table.

In each row of the table, I have four columns in that two are buttons. If I click that button I want the value of JSON `myobj[x].time`  of specific iteration.

Above code, it is always returning the last node of x. Here I want to generate an appropriate unique id of button. I'm new to js it would be a pleasure if someone would help in this.

Comment: FYI: Solutions based around IDs are not scalable and lead to problems like the one you are having. There are many ways to identify elements besides IDs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by passing `this` as parameter in the `onclick` like `onclick='popup(this)`. Here `this` will be the element in target , then in the function you can retrieve using `id` key.

An alternative and better way is used to add event listener using class

```js
var obj, dbparam, x, myObj, txt = "";
obj = [{
    "Segment": "Segment1",
    "time": "0:00:03:13"
  },
  {
    "Segment": "Segment2",
    "time": "0:00:03:13"
  },
  {
    "Segment": "Segment3",
    "time": "0:00:04:13"
  },
  {
    "Segment": "Segment5",
    "time": "0:00:05:13"
  },
  {
    "Segment": "Segment4",
    "time": "0:00:06:13"
  },
  {
    "Segment": "Segment7",
    "time": "0:00:10:13"
  },
  {
    "Segment": "Segment8",
    "time": "0:00:14:13"
  },
  {
    "Segment": "Segment9",
    "time": "0:00:13:13"
  },
  {
    "Segment": "Segment10",
    "time": "0:00:33:13"
  },
  {
    "Segment": "Segment11",
    "time": "0:00:21:13"
  },
  {
    "Segment": "Segment12",
    "time": "0:00:18:13"
  },
  {
    "Segment": "Segment13",
    "time": "0:00:07:13"
  },
  {
    "Segment": "Segment14",
    "time": "0:00:19:13"
  }
];
dbParam = JSON.stringify(obj);
myObj = JSON.parse(dbParam);

function segments() {
  document.getElementById("table").innerHTML = `<table border='1'>${
   myObj.map(function(item,index){
    return "<tr><td>"+item.Segment+"</td>"+
    "<td>"+item.time+"</td>"+
    "<td><button class='editBtns' id='x_"+index+"' onclick='popup(this)'>Edit</button></td>"+
    "<td><button>Save</button></td></tr>"
   }).join('')
}</table>`

}
segments();

function popup(elem) {
  console.log(elem.id);
}
// code for second option
[...document.querySelectorAll('.editBtns')].forEach((item) => {
  item.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    console.log(' From EventListener ', e.target.id)
  })
})
```

```html
<div class="table1" id="table">
</div>
```